# playgroundでグラフが表示されない

Tags: swift2, xcode7

xcode7.2.1のplaygroundでfor文などを使った際に
グラフが表示されません。
[image: グラフ]

何か設定などありますでしょうか？
ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

for文の中に明確に値を設定するような文(か宣言)を記述しないとグラフ表示はされないようです。for文の中に`let y = somei`のような行を追加してから、Show Resultマークをクリックしてみてください。